# How do I make my computer's firewall let devices on the same network in?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-vista, firewall, wamp

For obvious reasons, I want to access my computer's WAMP server from other devices (a smartphone and a tablet) in the same WLAN.

The `httpd.conf` part is okay, but I can't access my webapp unless I deactivate this Windows Vista's firewall.

Is there a **secure** way to enable *only* my devices to get in, without having to deactivate my firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A firewall is pretty much never "all or nothing"; you can allow specific addresses, ports, programs. Use **`wf.msc`** to for configuring the Windows Firewall in Vista and later.

For example, you can add a rule allowing connections to httpd.exe, and/or to port 80, and/or addresses from the same subnet (under "Scope" / "Remote addresses").

Answer (score 2):

Vista and above has this notion of "network location"s for this very purpose. The idea is that you tell it you are at a home and it will allow other devices with an IP address on your local network to talk to your machine.

Follow the instructions here [to set/change a network location for the firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/choosing-network-location#1TC=windows-7).

If you did not allow Apache to operate on either network locations, you can change it by following the steps [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7).

You can of course add advanced rules to Windows Firewall to allow certain IPs/ranges etc (particularly using [netsh advfirewall firewall](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947709) for command line or via the "Advanced Settings" option in the Windows Firewall control panel applet which is a short-cut to something someone else pointed you to, "wf.msc"), but I believe that is beyond the scope/interest of your question.

Though these are Windows 7 links, it didn't really change much since Vista.